# kafka record key extraction in filebeat

Tags: apache-kafka, filebeat

According to this [document](https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/master/libbeat/docs/outputconfig.asciidoc#key):

```
key

Optional Kafka event key. If configured, the event key must be unique and can be extracted from the event using a format string.
```

But, nowhere it specifies how to do it..

I have an event (json message) in file, that needs to be sent to kafka using **filebeat**.

```
 "message":
 {
    "name": "display",
    "id": "asdf-123",
    "type": "User",
    ...
 }
```

I tried having filebeat.yml like this:

```
filebeat.prospectors:
  - input_type: log
    paths:
      - ...
output.kafka:
  codec.format:
    string: '%{[message]}'
  hosts: ["localhost:9091"]
  key: '%{[event.id]}'
  topic: 'my-topic'
  ...
```

Here i am trying to extract `message.id` from json, to be used as kafka record key.
This does not work..

My question, how we format the message from filebeat to include dynamic keys..

Comment: Found a closely matching conversation here : https://discuss.elastic.co/t/is-it-possible-to-specify-a-partition-key-when-using-filebeat-to-send-to-a-kafka-topic/94732/4

This says we can extract json field.. but does not seems to working. what about nested json field ??

Comment: I think you'd have to add logstash to pull nested fields out. Otherwise, `event.message.id`